# Why do mobile viewport dimensions change if there is overflow in flexbox container with 'nowrap'?

Tags: css, flexbox

Unsurprisingly, if a parent with `display: flex`:
1. Has `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: nowrap` and,
2. Has any children that start wide (`flex-basis`) and don't allow shrinking (via `flex-shrink: 0`),
the content will exceed the bounds of the parent dimensions.

If this flex parent is the width of the screen, browsers generally just honor the 'nowrap' layout anyway and put up a horizontal scrollbar if the viewport gets too small. But on a mobile screen this isn't the only thing that happens. The window's opinion of its own viewport size seems to change, and it throws off the scale of the page.

I've recreated in a simplified page:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-child-text">Here's a bunch of text</div>
        <div class="flex-child-button">ButtonHere</div>
        <div class="flex-child-button">ButtonThere</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-bar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
}

#flex-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.flex-child-text {
    flex: 1 0 340px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.flex-child-button {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    height: 1rem;
    margin: 0px 0.25rem;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid #aaa 1px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}

#footer-bar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

[here it is in a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1h9bjr9w/6/)

The jsfiddle is mostly because visuals are helpful, but it can't recreate the bug. Simple resizing of a window doesn't do it - I've observed in Chrome mobile emulator and verified on an Android device. If any intrepid reader were willing to cut/paste/try on their own Chrome mobile, I've included a head tag in the fiddle code to ease that along.

Toggling `.flex-child-text` `flex-shrink` property between 0 and 1 changes the viewport dimensions (both width and height, seemingly proportionally). The footer, which gets position and dimensions from the outer container, is flung offscreen. This is also evidenced by consoling `window.innerWidth` - the result has changed when the layout has broken.

[Image - All elements contained within viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE4Fl.png)

[Image - Children break out of container, bottom-right of scroll dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgJ9h.png)

So to be clear, I understand why in the second image there is white space if you scroll to the right of the green container. What I don't understand is: 1. Why this also causes the y dimension to change like it does, and 2. Why an element `position: fixed` to `bottom: 0` or `right: 0` doesn't anchor to the side of the actual viewport in this special case.

Comment: Have you read, or aware, of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: @LGSon yes, I'd been working with that meta tag in the head already. Thought that may have something to do with it so I tested without it. If the flex children are sized up appropriately to break out of the viewport I observe the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `overflow: auto` to the outer `#container` makes it work. The offending content still pushes out of the flex container to the right (and can be scrolled to), but the elements that rely on viewport anchoring are now back in place.

Still not clear on why the layout broke in such a way that dimension y was affected, but this fix makes that not an issue. Got the idea in [this blog post](https://codepen.io/noahblon/post/practical-guide-to-flexbox-dont-forget-about-flex-shrink)